# Replace first line of a file and adding a new line with variables

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

I'm on an HP-UX/ksh UNIX box and I have files in which I want to always replace the first line with another line with content from variables.  Here is an example file and variables:

```
date=04_16_2016

var1=RM1
```

(var1 will be different at other times)

**file1.text :**

```
file=/home/user1/something_04_09_2016.txt
stuff
stuff
stuff
```

I want to replace completely erase that first line and replace it with something like this psuedo-code:

```
file=/home/user1/something_$var1_$date.txt
```

So the file will be like the following when done:

```
file=/home/user1/something_RM1_04_13_2016.txt
stuff
stuff
stuff
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have `date` and `var1` set, then you can do

```
sed "1 s:.*:/home/user1/something_${var1}_${date}.txt}:" file1.txt > file1.mod
```

The `sed s` is applied only to line `1`.

Answer (score 1):

another `sed` alternative

```
header="some string with $var and $formatted_date"
sed -i -e "1i${header}" -e 1d file
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `sed` is without the `-i` option (edit inplace), you can use `ed`.
Do not indent the code beneath, most things need to be at the start of the line.

```
newstring="/home/user1/something_${var1}_$(date +'%d_%m_%Y').txt"
ed -s input << EOF
1c
${newstring}
.
w
q
EOF
```